# Unable to set/get item in Asyncstorage in React Native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

While using Asyncstorage in React Native nothing gets executed set or get, it prints alert one but not myname. Can somebody suggest where is it getting wrong, I have tried .then also but it just returns 4 promises.

```
    setItem(){
      let username = 'Yogesh'
      AsyncStorage.setItem('myname', username)
    }

getItem = async() => {
    try{
        alert("one")
        let myname =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('myname')
        alert(myname)
    } catch(error) {
        console.log("Error", error)
    }
}
```

In render methods are called up like this:

```
 <Button
                title='Set'
                buttonStyle={styles.btn}
                textStyle={styles.btnText}
                onPress={() => this.setItem()}
            />
            <Button
                title='Get'
                buttonStyle={styles.btn}
                textStyle={styles.btnText}
                onPress={() => this.getItem()}
            />
```

Comment: check if you really get `myname` back from the `getItem` before `alert` it:
`let myname = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myname')
if (myname !== null){
    alert(myname);
}
else {
    alert('No name');
}`

Comment: It didn't go to if or else statements.  Nothing is executed after this line `let myname =  await AsyncStorage.getItem('myname')` console or alert`

Comment: Is this working like you want? https://snack.expo.io/B1zgnCf_G

Comment: did you import AsyncStorage? `import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native'`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure import AsyncStorage to file like this :

import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

Comment: Can there be any issue cos of react-navigation?

Comment: Can you try to "setItem" function async and "await AsyncStorage.setItem('myname', username)"